# how to replace url in css using regexp (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, url

```
var text = '#anything {behavior:url("csshover.htc");}'; //iam using " with url
text += "#anything {background:transparent url('img.png') no-repeat;}"; //iam using ' with url
text += "#anything {background-image:url('ok.jpg');}";
```

result

```
#anything {
    behavior:url("#");
}

#anything {
    background:transparent url('#') no-repeat;
}

#anything {
    background-image:url('#');
}
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `#` below with `$2` if you want to get the URL with single quotes.

```
var text = '#anything {behavior:url("csshover.htc");}'; //iam using " with url
text += ".regleft {background:transparent url('img.png') no-repeat;}"; //iam using ' with url
text += "#anything {background-image:url('ok.jpg');}";
text = text.replace(/url\((['"])(.+?)\1\)/g, "url('#')");
```

Comment: text = text.replace(/url\\((['"])(.+?)\1\\)/g, "url('#')");
Thanks,This code helped me in my project.

Comment: Your regex wipes out the `url()` part so you're just left with `'#'`.

Comment: I'd suggest adding ? after ['"] so you also get urls without quotes.
`'url(http://blabla.com)'.replace(/url\((['"]?)(.+?)\1\)/g, "$2");`

Answer (score 1):

For others who come here looking for a general solution that preserves both **whitespace** and **quotes**:

```
//Test data
var css = 'one url(two) url(\'three\') url("four")  url  (  five  )';

css = css.replace(

    // Regex
    /(url\W*\(\W*['"]?\W*)(.*?)(\W*['"]?\W*\))/g,

    // Replacement string
    '$1*$2*$3'

);

console.log(css);
```

outputs

```
one url(*two*) url('*three*') url("*four*")  url  (  *five*  )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GcsLQ/2/

```
var text = '#anything {behavior:url("csshover.htc");}'; //iam using " with url
text += "#anything {background:transparent url('img.png') no-repeat;}"; //iam using ' with url
text += "#anything {background-image:url('ok.jpg');}";


text = text.replace(/url\([^)]+\)/g, 'url("#")');
```

If you want the space formatting as well, do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GcsLQ/3/

```
var text = '#anything {behavior:url("csshover.htc");}'; //iam using " with url
text += "#anything {background:transparent url('img.png') no-repeat;}"; //iam using ' with url
text += "#anything {background-image:url('ok.jpg');}";


text = text.replace(/url\([^)]+\)/g, 'url("#")')
    .replace(/{/g,'{\n\t')
    .replace(/}/g,'\n}\n');
```

**EDIT:** Added quotes to the replaced URL.